# PHP preg_match return the string between two strings

Tags: php, html-parsing, preg-match

How can I get this link "http://example.com/view.php?id=5841" from the code:

```
<h3 class="coursename"><a class="" href="http://example.com/view.php?id=521">D<span class="highlight">LAW</span> <span class="highlight">130</span>Management</a></h3><div class="moreinfo"></div></div><div class="content"><ul class="teachers"><li>Teacher: <a href="http://example.com/">John</a></li></ul><div class="coursecat">Category: <a class="" href="http://example.com/">First</a></div></div></div><div class="coursebox clearfix even" data-courseid="5841" data-type="1"><div class="info"><h3 class="coursename"><a class="" href="http://example.com/view.php?id=5841"><span class="highlight">LAW</span> <span class="highlight">130`
```

I tried:

```
preg_match('/href="(.*)"><span class="highlight">LAW/isU',$BBB,$AAA);
```

And the result was:

```
http://example.com/view.php?id=521">D<span class="highlight">LAW</span> <span class="highlight">130</span>Management</a></h3><div class="moreinfo"></div></div><div class="content"><ul class="teachers"><li>Teacher: <a href="http://example.com/">John</a></li></ul><div class="coursecat">Category: <a class="" href="http://example.com/">First</a></div></div></div><div class="coursebox clearfix even" data-courseid="5841" data-type="1"><div class="info"><h3 class="coursename"><a class="" href="http://example.com/view.php?id=5841
```

Comment: do you want all the links, or links with id or on with particullar id , if you want all then this is enough `preg_match('href="(.*?)"', $data, $res);`
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
/href="(.[^<]*?)"><span class="highlight">LAW/isU
```

It is a simple way of telling Regex to find the shortest expression that matches the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

With an XPath query:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($yourHTML);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$link = $xp->query('//a[span[@class="highlight"]][starts-with(.,"LAW")][1]/@href')->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $link;
```

query details:

```
// # axe: anywhere in the DOM tree
a  # axe: a "a" tag
[span[@class="highlight"]] # predicate: the "a" tag has for direct child a "span" tag 
                           # with a "class" attribute equal to "highlight"  
[starts-with(.,"LAW")]     # predicate: its text content begins with "LAW"
[1]                        # predicate: first occurrence (no need to search another one)
/@href                     # axe: its "href" attribute
```

Comment: I am beginner programmer and i do not know how to use XPath query >> anyway  thank you very much

Comment: @Akram: the DOM is a tree representation of an HTML or XML document. XPath is a language designed to query this tree. Working example with your data: https://eval.in/457993